# Call to undefined method Infusionsoft\Api\Rest\ContactService::addWithDupCheck()

Tags: php, infusionsoft

This was working all this while with no issues and updates.

`$user_id = $infusionsoft->contacts->addWithDupCheck($contact, 'Email');`

Now all of a sudden it isn't

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Infusionsoft\Api\Rest\ContactService::addWithDupCheck() in
>   /home/user/public_html/infusionsoft/addContact.cli.php:29

```
~/public_html/infusionsoft$ cat composer.json
{
    "require": {
        "infusionsoft/php-sdk": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: "All of a sudden"? Have you compared the current version against the working version in your Git repository?

Answer (score 1):

InfusionSoft has replaced their older XML-RPC API with REST. REST is now default. So I had to do :
`$user_id = $infusionsoft->contacts('xml')->addWithDupCheck($contact, 'Email');`